# Update with join condition is taking too long in redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table in a Redshift cluster with 5 billion rows. I have a job that tries to update some column values based on some filter. Updating anything at all in this table is incredibly slow. Here's an example:

```
Update tbl1
set price=tbl2.price, flag=true
from tbl2 join tbl1 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id
where tbl1.time between (some value) and
tbl2.createtime between (some value)
```

I have sort key on time and dist key on id. When I checked stl_scan table, its shows that my query is scanning 50 million rows on each slice, and only returning 50K rows on each slice. I stopped the query after 20 mins. 
For testing, I created same table with 1 billion rows and same update query took 3 mins. 
When I run select with same condition I get the results in few seconds.Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct syntax is:

```
Update tbl1
    set price = tbl2.price,
        flag = true
from tbl2 
where tbl1.id = tbl2.id and
      tbl1.time between (some value) and
      tbl2.createtime between (some value);
```

Note that `tbl1` is only mentoned once, in the `update` clause.  There is no join, just a correlation clause.

Comment: As per the AWS-Redshift documentation both syntax are the same. Also I tried running your query and it is still taking me more than 20 mins.

Comment: @RedshiftGuy . . . That is interesting.  They are different in Postgres.